# ¿Cómo evito llamar dos veces a un jQuery?

Tags: jquery

He notado que al colocar esta línea en el **head** no funcionan mis líneas `<script>`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pero cuando lo pongo directamente en el archivo top.php si funciona y deja de funcionar un Slider y me sale esta leyenda

**LayerSlider: multiple jQuery issue**

*It looks like that another plugin or your theme loads an extra copy of the jQuery library causing problems for LayerSlider to show your sliders. Please navigate on your WordPress admin area to the main page of LayerSlider and enable the "Put JS includes to body" option within the Troubleshooting & Advanced Settings box.*

Cambio a la opción a **Put JS includes to body** y deja de salir la leyenda pero sigue sin funcionar el slider.
Creo que ***jquery.min.js*** u otro parecido se está llamando 2 veces; **¿cómo lo corrijo?**

Comment: Sin más código no podremos ayudarte. Cuelga algo de tus archivos tambien, donde lo colocas almenos. De paso echale un vistazo a [ask]

Comment: @GDP Encontré el problema cambié de Jquery al `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` Y ya todo aparece correcto; mis funciones sin afectar el Slider .

Esta linea llamando al Jquery está al inicio de mi archivo top.php, normalmente van en el `<HEAD>` pero me funciona al llamarlo desde un archivo interno.

Comment: Entonces seria que tus funciones o el slider no serían compatibles con una version mas avanzada. :)

Comment: El slider tiene la version 1.8.3, me puse a leer los archivos del plugin Rev-Slider

Comment: Ten cuidado con los plugin que usas. jQuery va por la v. 3. Si no han actualizado , da mala espina. Antes de instalar cualquier plugin fíjate en la última vez que lo actualizaron. Si tiene muchos meses/años sin actualizar puede ser un plugin abandonado que podría hacer a tu sitio vulnerable.